# Send Json inside FormData as File alongside files

Tags: json, file, form-data

I was wondering if it was ok to encode json data as a blob (using atob) alongside some other binary data to the server, and then reload the json file file into memory to save it in the database?
I am doing this in order to prevent multiple posts to the server, I could for example, send the json data, validate it, and when it's OK, I could send the files with some Ids, and then link the both of them server side.

but this method seems broken, because if the user leaves the browser while he is sending the data, and part of the files have been sent, then i'd have alot of uncomplete posts.

Thanks for your answers in advance.